# How to achieve cube effect in view pager in RTL mode?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I want to achieve a cube animation effect when swiping `ViewPager` fragments. like this:

[image]

I'm using this code to achieve that:

```
class CubeOutTransformer : ViewPager2.PageTransformer {
    override fun transformPage(page: View, position: Float) {
        val deltaY = 0.5F

        page.pivotX = if (position < 0F) page.width.toFloat() else 0F
        page.pivotY = page.height * deltaY
        page.rotationY = 45F * position
    }
}
```

But my current effect is like this:

[image]

That only happens when I'm in RTL mode and in LTR mode everything is OK. But I want to achieve that effect in RTL mode. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse a couple of things:

- The condition from `if (position < 0F)` to `if (position > 0F)`
- The rotation in Y direction from `45F` to `-45F`

```
class CubeOutTransformerRTL : ViewPager2.PageTransformer {
    override fun transformPage(page: View, position: Float) {
        val deltaY = 0.5F

        page.pivotX = if (position > 0F) page.width.toFloat() else 0F
        page.pivotY = page.height * deltaY
        page.rotationY = -45F * position

    }
}
```

Preview:

[image]